# knitr/Rmarkdown: Figures side-by-side with a single caption

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

In a `.Rmd` document there are several ways to produce figures side-by-side.  If the figures already exist, the easiest way for me is to use `knitr::include_graphics(c(fig1, fig2, ...))` [Thx: Yihui!]

But when I do this, I can't find a way to add an overall figure caption, as is easily done in LaTeX.
Here is an example:

**chunk**

````
```{r, out.width = "30%", echo=FALSE}
# two figs side by side
include_graphics(c("fig/mathscore-data.png",
                   "fig/mathscore-data-ellipses.png"))
```
````

Output:

[image]

If I add a `fig.cap` to the chunk options, I get two separate figures, each with the same figure caption.

````
```{r, out.width = "30%", echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Left: scatterplot of mathscore data; Right: Data ellipses for the two groups."}
# two figs side by side
include_graphics(c("fig/mathscore-data.png",
                   "fig/mathscore-data-ellipses.png"))
```
````

[image]

Is there some other way to do what I want -- two sub-figures side-by-side, with a common caption?

Comment: Is your output HTML or PDF or something else? What´s your YAML header?

Comment: the nice thing with rmarkdown is that you can (for pdf ) allwas fallback to latex so:

Comment: /begin{figure} /includegraphics[ ]{ }  ,etc will work.

Comment: Just FYI https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figures-side.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### its both possible in knitr or plain latex.

in **knitr** set the chunk option to:

```
echo=FALSE,out.width="49%",out.height="49%",fig.show='hold',
fig.align='center'
```

I used the **latex** package subcaption,

imported in the header-includes section of the YAML header.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "V"
date: "22 4 2020"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{subcaption}
---


# add Two figures with latex

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[]{CAT.png}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[]{CAT.png}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{This is the main caption - Years 2020 - 2030 - the main caption. }
\end{figure}

#  add Two figures with Knitr 


```{r, echo=FALSE,out.width="49%",out.height="49%",fig.show='hold',
fig.align='center', fig.cap="This is the main caption - Years 2020 - 2030 - the main caption."}
knitr::include_graphics(c("CAT.png","CAT.png"))
````

[image]

Comment: Thx @J_F what I was missing was `fig.show="hold"` for HTML output.

Comment: Is there a way to get an (a) and (b) or something similar below the two figures?